# Android Intent Service to run in separate process does not stop itself

Tags: android, service, android-intentservice

I have created an intent service that downloads some files, writes some of them to external storage and some data to my app's local database

It was working fine until I realised that the intent service runs in the same process of my app.

I want the service to do its job even if the app process terminates. I noticed that if I terminate my process, the intent service dies too and does not do the task.

So I read that I can run my intent service in a separate process which I done here

```
 <service
            android:name=".services.DownloadContentIntentService"
            android:process=":whatever"
            android:exported="false" />
```

Now the task runs in a separate process. It still runs if I terminate my app which is working.

However, I noticed that the intent service does not terminate itself once the task is done.

Even when I call stopSelf(). According to Android Studio, it is still alive.

What is happening?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Post your code please

Comment: I'm not sure at all how good it is But it should work. .you can use system.exit () after your intent service is done.  Try it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android is essentially Linux based, so processes should be viewed always in that context. Now, the `Service` is provided by Android, but the sandbox is provided by Linux. Moreover, things get more complicated, because there is JAVA in picture as well, and a Virtual machine essentuates things more. `stopSelf()` by a service does in no way mean that the process containing the service is killed. To kill a process, you need to execute `SIGKILL` aka `kill -9`

So, even when Android has been signaled for `stopSelf()` by the service, Linux may still decide to keep the process alive, especially because before terminating a process, the resources need to be GCed. Thus, `stopSelf()` is in no manner equivalent to `SIGKILL`, which would essentially mean that you are not able to see the service in `PS` list (or Android's process list) immediately